# CMD (command prompt) can't go to the desktop

Tags: windows, cmd

when I open the commend prompt the default line is this

```
C:\Windows\system32>
```

and I'm using SASS to convert a .scss file located located on my desktop.

I know the default line should be saying something like this C:\Users\the name of my machine

I type c:\Users\MyName\Desktop and hit enter I get this

> 'c:\Users\MyName\Desktop' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to use the change directory command 'cd' to change directory

`cd C:\Users\MyName\Desktop`

you can use `cd /d` to change the drive as well.

link for additional resources
http://ss64.com/nt/cd.html

-- Edit --

The above assumes that your desktop is in the normal location. Sometimes (eg. you are using onedrive) your desktop folder can be located elsewhere.

It appears that the way to find the current desktop folder is to look in the registry at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-tell-windows-which-desktop-folder-is-the/afe5ff10-95b7-40a3-ae98-555773e7e1f6

You can query this from the command line using the [reg query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-query) command.

```
reg query "HKCU/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Explorer/User Shell Folders" /v Desktop
```

Which will give you something like this

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Explorer/User Shell Folders
    Desktop    REG_EXPAND_SZ     %USERPROFILE%/Desktop
```

where `%USERPROFILE%/Desktop` is the desktop location in this example. You can then give that to the `cd /d` command.

```
cd /d %USERPROFILE%/Desktop
```

Comment: cd %userprofile%\desktop    will do does independantly for any user, without the need for adapting the code.

Comment: How about `cd ~\Desktop` as in Mac? Does it also work in Windows?

Comment: @ÖmerAn Unfortunatly no, tilde expansion like that is only from unix shells. When you first open the cmd prompt in non-admin mode it usually starts in the home folder so you haven't gone anywhere else you can just `cd Desktop`

Comment: `cd %userprofile%\Desktop` gives: `The system cannot find the path specified.`,  `cd \d %userprofile%\Desktop` gives: `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`   (and `echo %userprofile%` results in `C:\Users\Luuk`)

Comment: @Samuel: I changed the '\' to a '/' in `cd /d`, but still my Desktop is not found, because of Microsoft redirected it to `D:\onedrive\Bureaublad`, where Bureaublad is Dutch for Desktop